# Unwanted .map files generated

Tags: gulp

```
var gulp =require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    del = require('del');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./public/styles/sass/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/css/'))
});
```

I did not want .map files generated. I tried: {sourcemap: false} but nothing works. also the message said: gulp-ruby-sass: stderr: DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing

```
--sourcemap without a value is deprecated.
Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect.
```

Is there any way to stop .map files from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `gulp-ruby-sass` to version 1.0 and change the code:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
   return sass('./public/styles/sass/*.sass')
       .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/css/'))
});
```